# Different colors for facet_grid strip texts in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I want to set different colors for each `strip.text.x` in a `facet_grid` figure. I could find some Q&As about assigning different colors for `strip.background`, but could not see one for texts.

In the example shown below, the x-axis strip texts are '4', '5', '6', and '7'. What I want is, for example, assigning the red color for '4', the blue one for '5', and some other colors on the other texts. 
Does anybody happen to know how to do this?

I tried to change them via using `g <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p2))`, but it feels like I can only change the options of 'background rectangles' of the strips, not the texts themselves.

```
p2 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(drv ~ cyl)
```

[image]

Comment: in `theme(strip.text = element_text())` you can change the colour. You can add that as a ggplot layer to the end of your code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R ggplot2: change colour of font and background in facet strip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53455092/r-ggplot2-change-colour-of-font-and-background-in-facet-strip)